# Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not have a public property named 'i'

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using asp.net with Bootstrap. In the .aspx I have written the following code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" class="btn btn-warning" runat="server">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> Cancel</asp:Button>
```

I am using HTML5.

The error is:

**Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not have a public property named 'i'**.

Without ***i*** tag I can not display the image inside the button which is server side control.

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Partha

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<asp:LinkButton>` to add your icon to the button like below

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" CssClass="btn btn-warning" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting HTML between tags use CSS. Add `CssClass` property to button and in that class set `background-image` property to cancel button image

An example:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.submit 
{ 
border: 1px solid #563d7c; 
border-radius: 5px; 
color: white;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px; background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6); 
background-position-y: 465px; background-position-x: 5px; background-color: #563d7c; 
} 
</style> 

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit" CssClass="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, in the aspx marker file you can have plain html elements as well as ASP controls. These ASP controls render to corresponding html elements then. When you nest another tag inside an ASP control it automatically checks if the parent control has that `type` of property. So, as long as you are in design phase typing this

```
 <asp:Button  ID="btnDoSomething">
    <i class="glyphicon ">
 </>
```

is the same as writing this on the code file:

```
 btnDoSomething.PropertyWithTypei
```

If btnDoSomething control does not have a property of that type it the IDE will complain. The same thing applies here.